# Pulling cell values from Excel into Word (Runtime error 429)

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I've been having trouble taking cell values from excel and using them in a word macro (I'm trying to insert string values from sheet cells at various bookmarks in a word doc). Right now I'm just trying to be able to access cell values, but I'm coming up with an error 429 (ActiveX component can't create object). Any help/advice on how to approach pulling values from excel and using them in word would be appreciated.

```
Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim exWbs As Excel.Workbooks
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
Dim strWbName As String
Dim cisInfo As CIS

Sub PopulateDoc()
    Set exWb = New Excel.Workbook
    exWb = exWbs.Open("CIS.xlsx")
    exWb.Sheets("Property Information").Cells(2, 8).Value = "test"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a `New` instance of a `WorkBook` instead:

```
Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("CIS.xlsx")
```

(You also need to have added a reference to the *Microsoft Excel XX Object Library*)

Comment: I'm now getting an error 91 (Object variable not set) on that line